# Android Debugging in MotoG

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator, android-4.4-kitkat, motodev-studio

Bought the new **Moto G XT1033** last week, phone's working fine but as a developer I am finding it difficult in Debug mode,Even after Enabling USB Debugging option in Developer options...

Error coming as necessary **USB drivers** not found ...
Checked in Motorola site too, not available.

Didn't work in Both the Windows / Linux Platform

Suggest me where to **find** the necessary drivers and how to install the necessary **driver** for my **MotoG XT1033**, which enables me to work in **Debug mode** in Eclipse IDE.

Comment: Did you find your solution?

Comment: Did you find your solution ???

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22217792/android-moto-g-mobile-doesnt-show-in-the-devices-list-of-eclipse

Refer Above link it works for me.

Answer (score 9):

I found the Drivers

[Here is the forum](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2550635)

[Windows x64 Drivers](http://forum.xda-developers.com/attachment.php?s=ecaf1f42f67bd86e000fa833fac33245&attachmentid=2436165&d=1386325519)

When you download it just delete the img extention and run it.

Comment: I tried to install the drivers but my phone battery got dried and started rebooting wen i tried to install drivers ....wat could b the cause??

Comment: Phone battery dried? Install the drivers to your computer. And your device should be connected to computer via usb

Answer (score 7):

On the moto G, ( If you're running KitKat, not too sure about jellybean) go to settings, about Phone, And then tap build number repediately until it says you're a developer on the screen. Under the main settings menu, there should be an option for developer mode now. Hopefully that works, it did it for me.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this.  Is this documented officially anywhere?

Comment: You can read this here: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging

Answer (score 4):

I've had a similar problem, been uninstalling and reinstalling drives for the last 2 hours. The above recommendation of:

**Settings** >> **Storage** >> **Open Top right corner Action bar Menu** >> **USB computer connection** >> **Check Camera(PTP)**

Finally is what prompted my phone to accept a PCs (tried with two) RSA key for USB debugging.

Answer (score 1):

I still had to restart Eclipse for it to wake up.

So, to summarize, tap tap tap tap under Settings>Phone>Build.
Hook up device.
Pull Down USB device from header.
Select Camera PTP. An RSA Prompt comes up. Just press ok.

Relaunch Eclipse if you need to. (I had to).

Other phones - like an experimental Huwei for Turkcell I was using last year required the dev to go to the phone and punch in a key sequence.

I think this is going to become more common as time goes on.

Answer (score 0):

Try downloading from: 
https://motorola-global-portal.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/88481
Worked for me.

Answer (score -2):

Go to

```
 Settings >> Storage >> Open Top right corner Action bar Menu >> USB computer connection >>Check Camera(PTP)
```

The drivers will be installed.

Comment: Still same error prompts while choosing a running android device...debug state inactive