# android - Moto G mobile doesn't show in the devices List of Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

I am trying to connect a Moto G Mobile to Eclipse in My Windows 7 32-bit machine but It doesn't show on the devices List. For this, First I connected the device to machine via USB cable and then I chose the **PTP** mode and then I checked the "USB debugging" option in devices settings. After a few seconds it says "Drivers was installed Unsuccessfully". At that time, I had uninstalled the device drivers in the device manager of my machine and then disconnected and connected again. It said "Drivers was installed successfully" and then I updated the drivers in the device manager and then set the drivers(google-drivers from SDK).But it doesn't show in the devices List. what did I do wrong here?

Comment: did you solve it ?? I also facing same problem ..

Comment: @SatyenUdeshi: Not yet.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Hopefully i am able to find one solution for this issue.

Download '**Adb Driver Installer**' from here http://adbdriver.com/downloads/

after this connect your **Moto G** and start the **AdbDriverInstaller.exe** it will list your device and then press install.

Hope it Works !

**Note : **

It worked for me on Windows 7 but not on Windows 8

**Edit**

this link http://dl.xda-developers.com/attachdl/3b2765b7b77976f98576f76f7f549956/532c41bc/2/4/8/0/3/9/6/howto_driver.zip

help me solve this issue on windows 8.1

Just go through the photos inside it for additional assistance go through this link

http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2588979

All the best !

Comment: need to disable driver signature verification on Windows 8.
This worked for this.

Comment: open device manager and do the following steps and make sure u have already installed google_usb_drivers..https://www.dropbox.com/sh/olcjp9h5wxvsmds/AABwvXXQDsJNoRa-1HRDVLzZa  hope this helps

Comment: When i will try to install my android mobile into my system i got an issue like this http://picpaste.com/Capture-NHeAHZ8N.PNG

Comment: have you installed the google usb_driver ? if not then install those drivers . Hope this helps

Comment: this helped me when trying to flash another ROM onto my moto g. it couldn't find the defvice with adb, now it does! GREAT!

Answer (score 16):

After I changed "connected as" from Media device (MTP) to Camera (PTP), adt devices and eclipse started showing my moto-g. :)

Comment: This worked for me. To change that, after you connect your device check on the notification center and tap the "Connected as XXX, Touch for other USB options"

Comment: Thank you, thank you sandeep and Zequez. "What is the secret step that nobody is telling me?" I kept asking myself. Now I know. Seems incredibly obscure that changing from "media" to "camera" is the thing to do to actually enable usb debugging.

Comment: This is the only one step that really worked after wandering in 100s of other places (y)

Answer (score 13):

1) Tap Settings
2) Tap about phone
3) Tap Build number 7 Times

Now you will get the developer options

Comment: Yes. I have windows 7 & Eclipse and motorola drivers:
https://motorola-global-portal.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/88481/
No problems at all.

Comment: Holy moly! It works, thank you! I'm perplexed at the obscurity of this feature.

Answer (score 12):

This Motorola tool installed the USB drivers needed

https://motorola-global-portal.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/88481/action/auth

Answer (score 4):

Here is the detailed steps to show your motog2 (Marshmallow) in Android Studio on Windows 7 operating system. I didn't try in Eclipse. Hope it helps in Eclipse too.

1. Enable the Developer options
   a. go to Settings --> About phone --> Build Number (Tap 7 times)
   b. You would get a successful message saying that you are now a developer
2. Download the motorola OEM driver at
   https://motorola-global-portal.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/88481
3. Turn on the developer option and then turn on usb debugging
   a. go to Settings --> Developer options
   b. Turn on --> press ok
   c. and then Enable the USB debugging --> Press ok
4. Now goto step 7 directly, if it doesn't work then follow the steps in order.
5. Now start --> All programs --> right click on Computer --> Manage
6. go to Other devices --> XT1068 
   a. right click on the XT1068 --> Update Driver Software 
   b. Click on "browse my Computer for driver software"
   c. Click on "Let me pick from a device drivers on my computer"
   d. Click on "Android device"
   e. Then you would be shown with 2 ADB Interfaces
   f. Click on "Motorola ADB Interface" --> Next
7. Select USB configuration in "Charging only" mode
   a. go to Settings --> Developer options
   b. under Networking --> click on "Select USB Configuration"
   c. select "Charging only"
   d. You would see a succesful message on computer saying the ADB Interface is installed"
8. Now run the app in Android studio, the device will be shown.

Hurray!!!!! Enjoy. Let me know if it didn't work

Answer (score 1):

To connect moto-g  with your eclipse with **windows 8.1**, please take updated eclipse adt bundle  from the google deveopers site and install motorola drivers from the [this drivers link](https://developer.motorolasolutions.com/docs/DOC-1880). seriously i dont know which is has to be done to make it work. but i did both and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

The above suggestions didn't work for us but the following did:

Make sure you have installed the [Motorola drivers](https://motorola-global-portal.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/88481) (bloatware) first.

Then from Windows Device Manager, right-click device called Motorola ADB Interface (or similar).
Select "Browse my computer for driver software"
Set location to "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Motorola Shared\Mobile Drivers"
or
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Motorola Shared\Mobile Drivers"

Click "Next" and all should be good :-)

Answer (score 1):

I am using windows 8.1. Have tried all the possibilities. Updating the USB driver worked for me.
Download the USB driver for Motorola device from https://motorola-global-portal.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/88481