# How to debug android app using moto g device in windows

Tags: android

please help me how to debug my android application in moto g dvice in windows platform.In my app am getting problem in running service in background.

Comment: try [this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22531203/2982225)

Comment: Are you able to see `Developer Option` in Setting screen of your device? Also, you have to explain a bit your issue that what have you tried and what steps you followed to achieve goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to the settings of your device and check for `Development Tools` or `Developer Options`.If its not available then go to `About Device` there tap 7 times on Build Number you will see Developer Options in your Settings Menu.Click on it and enable Debugging option.

In your Eclipse,right click on the your project,select `Run as>>Run Configurations>>Target>>select Always prompt Device.`

Now Whenever you will run your application it will show options,select your device.
Hope it helps you .All the best :)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the above solution you need to do this to:

The Android development guide (http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html) says that USB drivers are required for debugging on a device connected by USB.

You can install the USB driver by going to https://motorola-global-portal.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/88481/action/auth

After installing the driver you can see the device in the Devices section of your IDE.

Answer (score 0):

We can debug android application by following below steps

1. Enable USB debugging in developer options(if you are not able to see developer option then go to settings -> About Phone and press more than 5 times on build number then developer option will be enabled)
2. Install ADT plugin in eclipse
3. Connect your phone via USB cable
4. In eclipse change to DDMS perpective mode and there you can see Logcat panel and where we can live phone logging