# My android phone is not getting detected in eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-emulator

I was using my micromax canvas A116 device to test my application from past 1 year, it was getting detected and I was installing my app in the device successfully.

But recently I changed my laptop. I copied the entire workspace and eclipse from my old laptop. So in new laptop when i open eclipse and try to run the android app on my device its always opening emulator, eclipse is not showing my phone under devices tab.. Please anybody know any solution?

Comment: have you checked device driver issue?

Comment: Check the drivers on new laptop, also check in `cmd`. Write `cd` and path to `<sdk>/platform-tools/` then write `devices` it prints a list of all attached emulator/device instances.

Comment: thanku guys i got the answer from this link      http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/oem-usb.html                      i updated my driver, its working fine now

Answer (score 0):

Have you double checked that your phone has USB-debugging mode enabled in Developer Options? I know I was frustrated the other day when Android Studio couldn't detect my device.

Edit: I CANT comment unless I have 50 reputation..Thanks for downvoting for such a lame reason.

Comment: You're welcome :) A good read : http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead

Comment: @2Dee Oh I see what you did there. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

I have given an answer for the same problem you might check the following link
[Device Doesn't show up in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22217792/android-moto-g-mobile-doesnt-show-in-the-devices-list-of-eclipse/22531203#22531203)

Hope this helps!!

Comment: You should mark the question as duplicate instead ...