# Sony Xperia Z4 tablet not found by adb

Tags: android, usb, adb

I got a Sony Xperia Z4 tablet and would like to display the Chrome console to debug a website.

What I did:
* connected tablet to my dev machine
* Enabled the developer options in the device settings
* also enabled usb debugging
* the tablet is recognized by windows explorer

So everything seems fine to me. However, when using "C:\adb> adb devices", the device won't show up.

I also tried :

- "adb kill-server"&"adb start-server"
- running adb as administrator
- installing Google USB Driver from Android Studio > Tools > Android > SDK Manager.

I've read that the USB connection type should be switched from MTP to PTP. But I can't find this option on the tablet.

Can you please give me any hints what I could check additionally or what the problem might be?

I am running Windows10 x64. Thanks!

Comment: you can see this thread http://stackoverflow.com/a/22531203/2641726

Answer (score 1):

This site saved me!
http://adbdriver.com/

Simply download the ADBDriverInstaller, then follow the instructions here:
http://adbdriver.com/documentation/how-to-install-adb-driver-on-windows-8-10-x64.html

After installing, my tablet showed up in "C:\adb> adb devices" but was unauthorized.
The popup then appeared on the tablet showing RSA fingerprint, I clicked "OK" on it, then my tablet was authorized.

I could see my device in `chrome://inspect` and keep following this tutorial:
https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging

Answer (score 0):

Once you have the latest Google USB Driver.  Connect your device to your PC via USB.

**My Computer->Properties->Device Manager->Right Click Device(Sony)-> Select Driver Tab -> Update Driver**

Now locate and install latest Google USB Driver manually. In my case it was located under

**C:\Program Files\Android\android-studio\sdk\extras\google\usb_driver**

Once that is done you'll get a confirmation dialog.

After driver is installed you might have to reboot your device.
Make sure you are running latest platform tool by running adb version.

**adb version**

After reboot and version check you should do:

**adb devices**

As soon as ADB server starts you will get a pop on your phone to accept RSA fingerprint of the PC. Once you accept the RSA fingerprint you are all set to debug Sony Tablet.

Comment: Thanks, but my there's no sdk folder in C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio.
I'm pretty sure I've installed the SDK as well while installing Android Studio.
I downloaded and copied the Google usb_driver in the repository you mentioned (that I created), then updated the driver like you said: no confirmation dialog showed up.

Comment: In your Android studio go to, Android Studio > Tools > Android > SDK Manager. here you can get your Android Sdk Location. From there you can get your usb_driver location.

Comment: ah that's great. Thanks